# Wordpress: Advances Custom Field multiple select

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I’ve been wracking my brain tonight trying to figure out how to display multiple labels from a select field.

First I tried it with a single field and that is working. Now I want to make use of multiple fields but can't get it working. Can someone help me?

Thanks!

```php
<?php if ( get_field( 'locationCompany', $joboffer->ID) ) : ?>
    <span class="company-compact"><? echo (get_field('locationCompany', $joboffer->ID))?></span>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you enable the `Select multiple values?` in the ACF settings. Here's your code:

```
<?php

    $locationcompany = get_field( 'locationCompany', $joboffer->ID); 

    if ( $locationcompany ) : 

        foreach ($locationcompany as $value): ?>

            <span class="company-compact"><?php echo $value; ?></span>

        <?php 

        endforeach;

    endif; 

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for you help! Rreally appreciate it.

Comment: Hi Romel. Just a quick question: how can I achieve the same on:

    <div id="job-offer-filter" class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 height-130 job-offer-card all <? echo (get_field('company', $joboffer->ID))?> <? echo (get_field('locationCompany', $joboffer->ID))?> <? echo (get_field('workingtime', $joboffer->ID) === "fulltime" ? "Fulltime" : "Parttime")?> <? echo (get_field('jobCategories', $joboffer->ID))?>">

In particular the 'locationCompany' part. I want to include the outcome as an class. This works with one outcome but not with multi select. Thanks you!

Comment: I need to know more, you just the value of the selected location right?

Comment: I added an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same approach as above but you need to wrap the whole `div` with the `foreach`:

```
<?php 

$locationcompany = get_field( 'locationCompany', $joboffer->ID); 

if ( $locationcompany ) : 

    foreach ($locationcompany as $value): ?>

        <div id="job-offer-filter" 
            class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 height-130 job-offer-card all 
            <? echo (get_field('company', $joboffer->ID))?>
            <? echo ($value) /*** HERE ***/?>
            <? echo (get_field('workingtime', $joboffer->ID) === "fulltime" ? "Fulltime" : "Parttime")?>
            <? echo (get_field('jobCategories', $joboffer->ID))?>">

    <?php 

    endforeach;

endif; 

?>
```

Please note if this `div` is in the same file with the span tag from above, you can just put this `div` inside the `foreach`. To avoid repetition of code.